# Uploading package to PyPi - but can't access any modules?

Tags: python, pypi

It's my firs time trying to create and upload my own package. Here it is -> https://pypi.org/project/testeroozz/0.2/#files

The problem is that when I `import testeroozz` and then run `dir(testerooz)` on it - I don't see either of: `sum_module` (the file holding the class), `Summation` (the class) or `great_summation` (the method). And so naturally I can't use either of those and get errors of the form:

```
AttributeError: module 'testeroozz' has no attribute 'sum_module'
AttributeError: module 'testeroozz' has no attribute 'Summation'
AttributeError: module 'testeroozz' has no attribute 'great_summation'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the classes and functions that you want to access in your `__init__.py` file which is in `testeroozz` package.

Your `__init__.py` file is currently empty.

It should be:

**__init__.py**

```py
from testeroozz.sum_module import Summation
```

You can refer to [this article](https://medium.com/@joel.barmettler/how-to-upload-your-python-package-to-pypi-65edc5fe9c56) to learn more on publishing your Python project to PyPI.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I do want to ask though - I've seen a ton of posts about updating $PYTHONPATH instead of using __init__.py, and I just couldn't get that approach to work. Is there a chance it's depreciated or something? Eg I can't get any of this advice to work, if I treat file as local -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder?rq=1